# why can't I see kibana in my browser? instead of it, I see the classic error 404 not found

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have been trying to instal elasticsearch with all its components; the first time it was great but I'm a beginner in in IT, so I decided unistall it to practice, them when I tried to install it again, I got the error I mentioned before.

I gotta be honest guys! I didn't know that when you uninstall elasticsearch you uninstall its components, so i tried to uninstall kibana too, but I think I deleted files that might be I've shouldn't.

this is the gui I used to install it
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elastic-stack-on-ubuntu-18-04-es

The server has Ubuntu 18.4 and it has nginx intalled correcty.

I hope you can help me please!

Answer (score 0):

Can you check these below points:

1. Elasticsearch is up and running
2. Kibana is properly configured with Elasticsearch (check kibana's configuration file)
3. Check Kibana logs for error

If you have covered the above 3 points and still facing issue, then please provide the kibana configuration file and kibana logs here.